# Error while running React native iOS app in emulator

Tags: react-native

I got some problem with my react-native app. I'm currently using React Native 0.31. The app can be built successfully by running `react-native run-ios` but when it starts in the emulator I get the following screen:

[image]

When I run Chrome debug then I get the following errors:

[image]

Everything works fine in Android. The problem is only in iOS. It could have happened after I upgraded React native version from 0.27 to 0.31 but I haven't been worked with the iOS app since then. Anyone has met this issue?

Comment: Do you have RCTWebSocket.xcodeproj in your `Libraries`? (Open project with Xcode and search the left sidebar)

Comment: @Mike Grabowski Yes, I have it.

Comment: show some codeline

Comment: I could but I don't really know which part to show.

Comment: show file where `this._nativeModule.addListener` is implemented

Comment: @stereodenis That's the problem because I haven't found something like that yet.

Comment: what about chrome debugger? look at stacktrace of error

Comment: @stereodenis my second image is from chrome debugger. It tells me basically the same things like the first one.

Comment: click on caret to open stacktrace

Comment: @stereodenis sorry for late answer. I did that but it did not help me to find the problem. It occurs only if I try to run the project from the command line with `react-native run-ios` but it works fine if I start it from Xcode.